# Why isn't the surface code limited to 2 qubits?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

Reading about surface codes I see that N+1 data qubits and N measurement qubits produce only 2 logical qubits. Does this mean that I can only do single qubit computation with such a surface code? If so how do we achieve multiple qubit computation using surface codes?

Relevant articles:

- [State preservation by repetitive error detection in a superconducting quantum circuit](http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.7403) - J. Kelly, R. Barends, A. G. Fowler, et al.
- [Quantum codes on a lattice with boundary](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9811052) - S. B. Bravyi, A. Yu. Kitaev

Comment: You can just take many surface codes.  You just need to couple them.  Or you could use a surface code with lots of holes.